# Strange address appearing in my Gmail's last account activity

Tags: gmail, security

I was checking the last account activity in my Gmail, found the following line:

> Access type: Browser
>
> Location:
>   2001:6b0:1:1fe0:22cf:30ef:fe7c:4000 (A
>   number in this format)
>
> Date: 01 Jul

What does that sequence of numbers mean?

And can I find where the computer is located?

Comment: [According to WHOIS](http://www.db.ripe.net/whois?form_type=simple&full_query_string=&searchtext=2001%3A6b0%3A1%3A1fe0%3A22cf%3A30ef%3Afe7c%3A4000&do_search=Search), the address belongs to Royal Institute of Technology, Sweden.

Comment: I've also seen this, and between the fact I have two step authentication (so even if you know my password you still can't login) and I'm hundreds of miles away from the other state mentioned, I have no idea why but I'm 110% sure my account is secure.

Answer (score 9):

That's an IPv6 address.  Someone is connecting from a host with an IPv6 address, rather than one with the usual IPv4 addresses you're probably accustomed to.

To find out where an IPv4 or IPv6 address is located, you can start with querying WHOIS.ARIN.NET.  If it's not in North America, you will see a reference to the appropriate network numbers registrar.

ARIN.Net (see WHOIS query input box in top-right corner)
  http://www.arin.net/

Wikipedia provides a good introduction to IPv6:

Wikipedia - IPv6
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Additionally, for more technical information about IPv6, one very helpful resource is the #IPv6 channel on the FreeNode.Net IRC network:

FreeNode.Net web-based IRC client on the IPv6 channel
  http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=IPv6

Comment: To make sure the IPv6 address connections aren't you, go into your Network Adapter settings and disable the IPv6 protocol plugin. That way, your computer doesn't use IPv6, even by accident.

Comment: @djangofan:  That won't work if going through NAT or a proxy.

Comment: ...could we *please* stop with "disable IPv6" answers?

Answer (score 2):

That's an [IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6). Google recently pushed hard in the IPv6 direction.

So, I don't think you have anything to be concerned about. Normal stuff.