# A suspicious app was blocked from accessing your account - How to check IP or app name?

Tags: google-account, security, google, authentication

Last days **Google** is sending me a "A suspicious app was blocked from accessing your account".

I'm a developer and it can be one of my apps but I can't find a way to see what `IP` or App name is it.

Is there a way to see the IP? I don't understand why they don't provide such information right there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://gmail.com
2. Click on Details (it's near the bottom right corner of the Gmail mailbox screen)

---

They used to show the IP address (see [“Suspicious sign-in prevented”. Suspicious or not?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28842/88163)). Only Google could say why they stop sharing it in the alert.

Related

- [Strange address appearing in my Gmail's last account activity](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17086/88163)
- [How accurate is the Gmail account activity listing?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66639/88163)
- [How to see time that one IP login on Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95348/88163)